# Vertically align content & 2 lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have 5 boxes that contain text that changes on hover.

However if the 'content' of a box has more than one line, it pushes the other boxes down slightly.

Also, how do I center the content vertically? Line-height does the job-ish but some of the text is more than one line. Also vertical-align seems to apply to the whole div rather than just the text in content

```css
 .image { 
    width: 204px; 
    height: 204px;
    background-image: url('imglink');
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    }

    .image:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    
    }

    .image:after { 
    width: 204px; 
    height: 204px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Content is inserted */
    content: 'This text is already there';

    }

    .image:hover:after{
    background-image: url('/imglink');
    cursor: pointer;
    content: 'This text will appear on hover';

    }
```

```html
 <div class="image">
     </div>
```

Here's the CSS, identical for all 5 boxes except different content.
Having massive difficulties sorting this as searching for "content" on Google doesn't really come up with the CSS "content"

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/su8bytdc/7/

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish besides aligning vertically. Can you fiddle it? jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Gacci Yeah here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/su8bytdc/7/. As you can see if you hover over one, the others go down

Comment: try to define `line-height: 204px;` for `.image`

Comment: max-height: 204px;overflow:hidden; for .image could also help.

Comment: @Banzay Line-height does indeed centrally align nicely, however I have some text that is 2 lines long :/ so I have to find a different way

Comment: @aVC That prevents the other boxes from being pushed down but half the sentence of the "content" now disappears

Comment: Please check this link:-http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: i tried it and it worked!

Comment: **I have moved my comments to an answer below. Please see the answer before following bad advice.**

Comment: If you want to center the content vertically then MassDebates's answer is correct. If you want to keep the text at the top then Gacci's i answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to your :after selector and `position: relative` to your div `.image`.

To align the content horizontally just add `text-align: center` to `.image` and `justify-content: center` to the :after element

So your updated code would look something like this

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 204px;
  height: 204px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 22px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.image:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Content is inserted */
  content: 'This text is already there Even multiple lines';
}
.image:hover:after {
  text-align: center;
  content: 'This text will appear on hover';
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: That works! Kinda..The first text (before hover) is not horizontally aligned, also for only 3 of the boxes, the hover text is not horizontally aligned :p but it is for the other two

Comment: Sry, my bad thought you wanted the content to be vertically aligned. Updated the snippet.

Comment: Yep that works, I've never heard of display: flex; before so I'll have to look into that

Comment: Definitely do that. It's called Flexbox and it's a really great new layout module in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so try adding `vertical-align: top` to your image class

```
.image{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, vertical-align is something I've been trying as that's what previous SO questions have said

Comment: @hulkinBrain Not working for me in all browsers? :S Nor in the fiddle either, unless I stuck it in the wrong place? I put it at the bottom of the .image class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
.image img {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
 ====================================
   Base styling, to make the demo more fancy
   ==================================== */
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #2C3D51;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 
}



h2 p {
 text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ECF0F1;
}

section {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #E74C3C;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: .2em;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<section class="text"> <h2>Text</h2>  <p>I'm vertically aligned! Hi ho Silver, away!</p></section><section class="image">  <h2>Images</h2>  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=120%C3%9770&w=120&h=70">
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the line-wrap issue, just put `overflow: hidden` on the container element. Beware, however that this will prevent all text from overflowing meaning if you later want to have a lot of text inside a box it will be hidden.

To center text inside of the box remove width and height from the pseudo elements and use the transform hack. Use this on the elements you want to center (remember to make its container relative):

```
position: absolute; (relative could also work here)
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Finally, all of these issues are no longer issues when using flexbox, so I would suggest learning that since it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/4tmx5f46/

```
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  vertical-align:middle;
```

The font declaration was causing the dropdown of the boxes. You'll need 'vertical-align:middle;' on the boxes themselves to prevent this.

Aligning the content in the middle with vertical-align is likely a bad idea here. Vertical Align can be a real scumbag.

**source:** http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/

That said, You should check out this guide. 
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

---

if you insist on centering it this way, then I would suggest you modify the content being placed by using a conjunction of ::before and ::after -> Using ::before to knock everything down by 50%, and then starting the ::after with the real content.

(or just absolutely position, transform, and be done with it)

If you want an example of what I'm describing, comment, and I'll crank out something for you.

---

Apologies for the mixup earlier. Grabbed a wrong tab's URL

Comment: Yes sorry that is not my code, I tried the "clean-up" thing on JSFiddle (first time using it) and it changed that, confused me lol The fiddle you linked me has the line-height problem, notice "hover" is underneath the boxes :L

Comment: 2 secs. I think I linked someone else's fiddle.

Comment: For some reason it was a combination of your fiddle + SvenL's solution that got it working. Really really weird one this